# How do I make a DataGrid always display its column headers in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm porting a Silverlight application to WPF for a project at work, and I've run into a small cosmetic issue. In the Silverlight application, the Datagrid's ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection that is initially empty. When I first load the application, the column headers are displayed, even though the DataGrid itself is empty. I am now trying to achieve the same thing in the WPF application. The ObservableCollection and Datagrid are both the same, but now the column headers only appear when I add a row to the Datagrid. The XAML for my Datagrid is as follows:

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="196" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="375" Width="775" ItemsSource="{Binding source}"
                        RowBackground="#A5BACA" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="documentsDG"
                        FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
</DataGrid>
```

Like I said, adding and removing rows works fine, it's just that I would like to find a way to make the column headers display without any data in the Datagrid. Also, I've tried starting the application with an empty row in the Datagrid, which does make the column headers appear, but it looks messy. If I remove that row from within the application, the column headers remain, but if I remove it on window load, they disappear.

So, any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need anything more on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're autogenerating the columns.  If you manually define the columns they'll be visible even when your collection is empty.

Also see:
[WPF Toolkit Datagrid Headers and Empty Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682586/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-headers-and-empty-source)

Comment: Yep, that worked, thank you. It didn't work at first, but then I realized I needed to bind each column to a field of my ObservableCollection. Once I did that, it worked just how I wanted it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have AutoGenerateColumns="True", however, you do not specify any Grid columns. From the behaviour you describe, it seems that once the context of the grid is populated it can read the attributes of the underlying object type in your collection. Prior to that, the grid has no knowledge of these attributes and, thus, cannot generate any columns.

No free lunch here, you will have to specify the grid columns in the xaml if you want to see them prior to populating the context.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Snap, but I already took care of this with Jason's answer last week. The app I needed it for has already been approved by the requester, so I'm not worrying about it anymore.